# Team Foundations Version Control - VersionControlServer - Get a list of folders and files from path?

Tags: c#, tfs

I am new to working with the TFS API. Is there a way to query the VersionControlServer to get a list of folders an/or files given a path??

> $/TeamProject/release/

Can I somehow get a collection of folders give this path?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var allItems = sc.GetItems("$/TeamProject/release/*");
var folders = allItems.Items.Where(t => t.ItemType == ItemType.Folder);

var folderPaths = folders.Select(f => f.ServerItem);
```

Comment: I was doing this with nested control statements. I like yours better :)